# C, while loop keeps repeating

Tags: c

so I built a very basic program according to The C Programming Language book, but when I run it, it keeps asking input after I enter one, the loop should ended when there are no inputs longer right? or Am I wrong? srry for my bad english

```
int main()
{
    long nc;
    nc = 0;

    while ( getchar() != EOF) {
    ++nc;
    }
    printf("%ld\n", nc);
}
```

Comment: Instead of putting any input press Ctrl+D, EOF is equivalent to Ctrl+D in C. As you are comparing getchar() to EOF, so you are being asked for input until you press Ctrl+D!

Cheers!

Comment: Exact duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358728/end-of-file-eof-in-c

Comment: sorry didn't expect this is a EOF problem and thanks very much

Comment: "when there are no inputs" -- and when, do you suppose, is that? The system can't read your mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop is expecting an EOF character to terminate, not just an empty string. *nix consoles typically translate a `Ctrl-D` on an empty line as EOF, in Windows I believe it's `Ctrl-Z` but I could be wrong.

Comment: By the way, *EOF* stands for *end of file*.  You are terminating the standard input stream when you enter the EOF character.

Comment: end-of-file is a condition, not a character ... note that getchar() returns int, not char, specifically because `EOF` doesn't fit in a char. On POSIX systems, getchar() returns EOF when the read() system call returns 0. For a file, that's when the end of the file is reached. For a terminal, that's when ctrl-D is entered immediately after a newline or another ctrl-D (that's right, ctrl-D in the middle of a line does not produce EOF -- try it if you don't believe it).

Comment: 1 more questions... why the EOF stroke must be pressed after a new line, it's not working when pressed after my input ex: test^Z

Answer (score 1):

No.

For standard input, you must input EOF manually. It's Ctrl+Z in Windows and Ctrl+D in Linux.

If you are using Linux and redirect standard input from file. It will end.

Answer (score 0):

This will keep reading input until it gets to an end-of-file.  If you're reading from the terminal (you haven't redirected the program to read from a file), it will only get an EOF if you explicitly give it one.  How you do *that* dpends on your OS, but on most UNIX-like systems, you can generate an explicit eof by hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to input `EOF`, anything other keyboard can't! So if you want to interrupt the loop, you must input the `EOF`.