# End of File in stdin

Tags: c, console, stdin, eof

A question about this has been asked here
[End of File (EOF) in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358728/end-of-file-eof-in-c)
but it still doesn't completely solve my problem.

`EOF` makes sense to me in any datastream which is not `stdin`, for example if I have some `data.txt` file, `fgetc()` will read all the chars and come to the end of file and return `-1`.

What I don't understand is the concept of `EOF` in `stdin`. If I use `getchar()`, it will wait for me to enter something, so if there is NOTHING written, End of File, (`EOF`) is not returned automatically?

So is it that only the user can invoke `EOF` in `stdin` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>? 
If so then what are some of the uses of `EOF` in `stdin`? I guess it tells the program to continue reading until the user invokes end of file? is this it?

Thank you

Comment: Yes only `ctrl+D` will give you EOF through stdin on unix. `ctrl+Z` on windows

Comment: maybe it's a question about waiting for actual input or not and this may depend on [input redirection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42831970/2932052)

Comment: Relevant: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110706-00/?p=10243

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> so if there is NOTHING written, End of File, (EOF) is not returned automatically?

No, it's not. It should be sent by the user.

> So is it that only the user can invoke `EOF` in `stdin` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>?

Yes, you can set the `EOF` indicator for `stdin` with a special key combination you can input in the console, for linux console that is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and for windows it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

> If so then what are some of the uses of `EOF` in `stdin`? I guess it tells the program to continue reading until the user user invokes end of file? is this it?

The use of it depends on whether you instruct the user to input the `EOF` explicitly or not, for example, I think `python` console will tell you something like `Press Ctrl+D or type quit() to exit`.

And `EOF` is not necessarily `-1` it's a macro and you should always use it to test for the `EOF` indicator. And more importantly `EOF` is not a character, it's a special value that indicates that the **E**nd **O**f **F**ile indicator is set.

Also, `getchar()` is equivalent to `fgetc(stdin)`.

Comment: thanks yeah that is what I was thinking too, also EOF might have uses then in emptying the input buffer? for example you can see if there is an EOF left in the buffer? It is slowly making sense

Comment: I don't think so, because `EOF` is not a character.

Comment: I will try it and see if it is left in the buffer

Comment: "you can insert EOF in stdin" mis-leads a bit.  Special key sequence like ^D signal to `stdin` that no more data will be appended.  I think these answer needs greater emphasis of your comment "`EOF` is not a character"

Answer (score 10):

In linux bash, if you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, it will generate `EOF`.

In Windows, the equivalent is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>

So, no, if *nothing written* to the terminal, that does not generate `EOF` automatically. The *scanning* function is in wait state then. So, without having any other inputs, in wait state, if <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is pressed, the key press is *translated* [by the terminal driver] to `EOF`.<sup>Note</sup>

Usually, once you key in some value and press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, the *scannning* function starts scanning. To *feed* an input for producing `EOF`, you need to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Related: Please reaed the [wiki entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file) for `EOF`

<sup>Note: With thanks to Mr Drew for the clarification.</sup>

Comment: It's worth pointing out that `CTRL+D` will generate EOF only if nothing has been entered. Otherwise, it'll push whatever data has been entered into `stdin`, as if you had pressed `ENTER` (without pushing a newline character).

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Thanks for the clarification sir. I'll add this info in my answer itself.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen is there a scenario where EOF can be left in the input buffer?

Comment: @Mcs what do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

`stdin` is a stream, data is not available until the user presses some keys. A file on the disk already has (a fixed amount of) content.

When reading from `stdin`, if `getchar()` doesn't wait for the user to input something then the program will always get `EOF`. That will make it impossible to use `stdin` as an input file.

Because `getchar()` waits for the user to input something there is no way to signal the input completed; that's why the operating systems provide a combination of keys that have this special meaning when they are pressed on the console.

Windows uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> and Unix-like OSes (including OSX) use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The file `stdin` is not always the user typing on the keyboard. If you redirect input to your program, it can be just a normal file.

```
program.exe <input-from-file.txt
```

What may be confusing you is that no giving input into a console window does not mark the end of the input. But think it the other way round: how could a user respond so quickly that the program would not terminate before it if the console would not do some buffering for the user? After pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> the user says this is a line of input. In other words: a program running in a console window always waits for the next input to come.

Most programs define a special phrase to end a console session. You probably know `exit`.