# C scanf stop in while

Tags: c

What do I need to correct in the code so that the loop will stop when the user stops entering data?

```
while(scanf("%i", &num)){   
    printf ("%#o %d 0x%X\n", num, num, num);<br/>
}
```

Comment: Your code is C and not C++!

Comment: `when the user stops entering data` when?

Comment: It looks like that your code is already doing what you're asking.

Comment: Im tested. I stopped writing and the program still works

Comment: [Does this question help you?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28216437/end-of-file-in-stdin)

Comment: @user202729 — doesn’t look like that to me. If it gets EOF, it goes into a tail spin.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Whoops... /// [What `scanf` function in C returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469643/what-scanf-function-in-c-returns).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this one

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int num;
    printf("Enter -1 for termination:");
while(scanf("%i", &num)>0 ){
        if(num<0)
        break;
  printf ("%#o %d 0x%X\n", num, num, num);

}

return 0;
}
```

If you type -1 or any character then termination will occur:

```
Enter -1 for termination:3
03 3 0x3
6
06 6 0x6
9
011 9 0x9
k

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 8.779 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `scanf("%i", &num)` only returns when the user presses return/enter, if they've previously typed some non-whitespace characters into the terminal.  If the user presses return on an empty line, the function will continue to wait for a non-whitespace characters.

If you type a non-numeric value, before you press return, you'll exit the `while` loop.