# How to use CTRL+C to stop getting input from the user?

Tags: c++, windows, console-application

I wanted to write a console notebook application which gets text from the user and saves it in .txt file. So, for inputting the text, I am using a while-loop:

```
while (getline(std::cin, line)) {
    myfile << line << "\n";
}
```

If the user is done writing the text, he/she must do something so the loop breaks. I have found something called *signal handling*, but do not know how to implement it in my code. I also tried *SetConsoleCtrlHandler* from Microsoft. How can I get the use of it, or are there any other ways to do the given task?

Comment: Did you try just doing `ctrl+c+enter`?

Comment: @NathanOliver yes it is just terminating the entire program

Comment: Entering EOF into stdin may also be a possibility: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28216437/end-of-file-in-stdin

Comment: Oh, I bet you need to clear the error state from the stream after the loop.

Comment: Note that Ctrl + z (Windows) or Ctrl + d (Linux) "naturally" signal EOF on standard-in (which makes `getline` fail). Linux console users usually know about Ctrl + d, it could be that your program needs to remind Windows users about the Ctrl + z option... -- I understood your question to ask for Ctrl + c *specifically*, hence this is not an answer.

Comment: Many Windows console users are aware of Ctrl+c, and expect it to end the whole application, not just input. I second @DevSolar's recommendation to use Ctrl+z.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, If you need only Ctrl+C as end of input:

Use SetConsoleCtrlHandler to detect Ctrl+C and set stop_flag (std::atomic_bool) for input stop.

Your input cycle should be like this:

```
Use while (!stop_flag) {
  if (_kbhit()) {
    auto symbol = _getch();
    // Process input char-by-char
    // ...
  }
  // May be add some sleep for 20 ms
  // ...
}
```