# The code is not running in terminal

Tags: c, terminal

I just started learning C and prior to that I have no knowledge of programming.

So I am trying to run this one stat program, that will read input and give you mean, variance and etc. I used terminal to run the program. I pretty much copied the code from the book I am using.

There was no error when I ran the code but when I enter the input, it didn't do anything. The code is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    float x, max, min, sum, mean, sum_of_squares, variance;
    int count;
    printf("Enter data: "); /* not included in the original code*/

    if( scanf("%f", &x) == EOF )
        printf("0 data items read.\n");
    else{
        max = min = sum = x;
        count = 1;
        sum_of_squares = x * x;
        while(scanf("%f", &x) != EOF) {
            count += 1;
            if (x > max)
                max = x;
            if ( x < min)
                min = x;
            sum += x;
            sum_of_squares += x * x;
        }
        printf("%d data items read\n", count);
        printf("maximum value read = %f\n", max);
        printf("minimum value read = %f\n", min);
        printf("sum of all values read = %f\n", sum);
        mean = sum/count;
        printf("mean = %f\n", mean);
        variance = sum_of_squares / count - mean * mean;
        printf("variance = %f\n", variance);
        printf("standard deviation = %f\n", sqrt(variance));
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [End of File (EOF) in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358728/end-of-file-eof-in-c)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code is fine as it is. You probably don't understand the "terminating condition". The program reads input in an infinite loop and you have to send `EOF` to terminate the loop.

To send EOF, you can use `ctrl + D` on unix systems and `ctrl + Z` on windows.