# Why is this character counting program in C doubling the value of the characters?

Tags: c

This example is from "The C Programming Language" by Dennis Ritchie and Brian Kernighan. It is supposed to take in characters given by user input, and then when an EOF is stated (using my Mac, it is ctrl-D), it ends the program and shows the amount of characters inputted. Instead it doubles the actual value of the amount of characters. Am I missing something? Thank you.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    long nc;

    nc = 0;
    while (getchar() != EOF)
        ++nc;
    printf("%1d\n", nc);
}
```

Comment: Because you are counting the `newlines` too. `getchar()` reads *every* input.

Comment: Also printing a long with the format specifier for int. Compiler should've warned you about that.

Comment: Besides the actual problem you're pointing out, your `main` function should have a return type. Also, like @user1320881 said, your format specifier for printf is wrong. It generates the following warning in GCC: `format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'long int'`

Comment: @user1320881 true, but in MSVC 32-bit `sizeof(long) == sizeof(int)`.

Comment: @WeatherVane true, and doubtful the OP is using MSVC 32bit "using my Mac"

Comment: @WhozCraig `long` in any implementation does not have to be larger than `int`.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358728/end-of-file-eof-in-c. This is question has already been asked.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understand now.

Answer (score 5):

It is not doubling the value, for example if you type :

```
a
b
c
Ctrl+D
```

you will see `6` cause there is a `line break` after each character like:

```
a\n
b\n
c\n
Ctrl+D
```

`\n` is considered as a character (if am not wrong, in mac the `line break` character is `\r`).

if you type :

```
abc
Ctrl+D
```

you will have 4 characters because of the `line break` at the end of the `abc` sequence.

---

**NOTE :** as other members noticed you are using the wrong formatting character for `long` type, it must be `%ld` but you are using `%1d` (1 instead of l) i think it is a mistake when you copied the code.

---

hope that answer you question.

Comment: UV for spotting the `%1d` typo.