# C - Counting numbers

Tags: c

I am a coding-beginner and would like to hear your advice relating to following solution of this exercise:

> Write a program that loops prompting for positive or zero integers of data type long. Then the number of digits the integer consists of (in decimal representation) should be printed to stdout. Entering a negative number immediately stops the program.
>   **Output examples:** 0 has 1 digit. 999 has 3 digits. etc.

I've written the code below and according to the tests I did, the program fulfills all given tasks. But what do you think about it? How can I improve it?

(And I also think that I am not allowed to use any finished helpful function in any c-library. It is just 'plain' C coding or so. Idk how to describe it.)

(The programming language is C)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
  long number;
  int n=0;

  do
  {
      printf("Enter a number: ");
      scanf_s("%ld", &number);

      if (number > 0)
      {
          while (number != 0)
          {
              number /= 10;
              n++;
          }
      }
      else if(number == 0){
          n = 1;
      }
      else {
          exit();
      }

      printf("The number you've entered has %d digits.\n\n",n);
      n = 0;

  } while (getchar() != 'EOF');

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `'EOF'`? Doesn't the compiler yell warning at you?

Comment: Sorry but SO is not the place to ask for opinion, only facts. http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: IMO, This question belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: `exit()` requires an argument.

Comment: `exit` requires `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: exit(EXIT_FAILURE) i mean, exit(EXIT_SUCCESS) in other way

Comment: You should check the outcome of the `scanf_s()` call. As it stands if it fails `number` will be used uninitialised, which might very well provoke undefined behaviour, anything may happen.

Comment: And looking at the code from the aesthetic point-of-view: The indention is inconsistent.

Comment: Also to make sure the prompt appears *before* the console asks for input call `fflush(stdout)` immediately after `printf("Enter a number: ");`.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers!

I did add the fflush and the EXIT_FAILURE including stdlib to my code. 

Questions:
1. Actually I wanted to use scanf(), but somehow my VS Studio 2017 tells me I should use scanf_s(). I looked after it, but I can only find http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/ .

2. Do you mean with "incosistent code" that I didn't always put my curly braces on the same 'place'?

Comment: I wasn't writing about "*inconsistent *code**". But yes, I was referring to the way the braces are placed.

Comment: `scanf_s()` as provided by VC is a MS extension to C. Ìf used correctly `scanf()` would do as well. MSDN docs for `scanf()` are here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9y6s16x1.aspx

Comment: Which compiler are you using?? You should definitely enable -Wall -Wextra -Werror options

Comment: Ok thanks, now I know the difference between scanf_s and scanf and sorry, I will use google a bit more longer to find such commands instead of asking here. I think Erik meant that ^^.

Comment: And the way I've solved this task is okay? I mean the if-else-statements and the do-while with that EOF 'query'.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question should be migrated to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: okay, sorry. I'll open a new thread on this site then, when this is rlly off-topic here. Thanks everyone for their time and help.

Comment: `'EOF'` and `EOF` aren't the same.

Comment: I've redirected the discussion to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/159583/c-counting-digits-of-numbers btw.

But no, the compiler does not warn me about 'EOF'.  And yes according to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/EOF/ and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/?kw=getchar I have to use EOF and not 'EOF'.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358728/end-of-file-eof-in-c you only get EOF, when you press ctrl+z to let the program now when you're done --> EOF.

Answer (score 0):

That getchar it's useless because EOF it's to say that a file it's over and you're not reading an file. Change that to while(number >=0).