# counting words from user input

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

the program cannot get out from the while loop `while (c != EOF)`

I have tried it in terminal

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    int c = getchar();
    int n = 0;
    while (c != EOF) {
        if (c == ' ') {
            while (c == ' ')
                c = getchar();
        }
        else {
            ++n;
            while (c != ' ')
                c = getchar();
        }

    }
    printf("\n%d", n);
}
```

it should show the no of words. however it is asking for input after input

Comment: you also have to manage newline, tab etc, what about to use _isspace_ to detect them. But is "aze,qsd" a word or two words ? do you follow the same definition as an identifier in C (including '_' as a word char) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [End of File (EOF) in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358728/end-of-file-eof-in-c)

Answer (score 4):

- > the program cannot get out from the while loop `while (c != EOF)`

  That's because you don't test for `EOF` in the inner `while`-loops:

  > ```
  > while (c == ' ')
  >     c = getchar();
  > ```

  *~>*

  ```
  while (c == ' ' && c != EOF)
      c = getchar();
  ```
- You tagged your question *kernigham-and-ritchie*. I hope you're just using the book and don't intend to also learn that pre-standard<sup>*)</sup> style of C.
- The return type of `main()` is missing.
- When a funktion takes no arguments in C it's parameter list should be `void`, so

  ```
  int main(void)
  ```
- I'd suggest you do

  ```
  int ch;
  while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
      // process ch
  }
  ```
- > ```
  > c == ' '
  > ```

  There is other whitespace besides space. See [`<ctype.h>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/) for a list of funktions for character classification.

---

#### Example:

```
#include <stddef.h>   // size_t
#include <stdbool.h>  // bool, true, false
#include <ctype.h>    // isalnum()
#include <stdio.h>    // getchar(), printf()

int main(void)
{
    size_t num_words = 0;
    bool in_word = false;
    int ch;

    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (!in_word && isalnum(ch)) {  // new word begins. isalnum() or isalpha()
            in_word = true;             // ... depends on your definition of "word"
            ++num_words;
            continue;  // continue reading
        }
        else if (in_word && isalnum(ch)) {  // still inside a word
            continue;  // continue reading
        }

        in_word = false;  // when control gets here we're no longer inside a word
    }  // when control reaches the end of main() without encountering a return statement
       // the effect is the same as return 0; since C99 *)

    printf("Number of words: %zu\n\n", num_words);
}
```

For better variable-locality maybe a `for`-loop should be preferred:

```
for (int ch; (ch = getchar()) != EOF;)  // ...
```

<sup>*) Language Standards:

C99: [ISO/IEC 9899:TC3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

C11: [ISO/IEC 9899:201x](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf) (draft close to the final standard)

C18: [ISO/IEC 9899:2017](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf) (proposal)</sup>