# asking the user for values until they signal end-of-file

Tags: c

I'm having trouble using EOF adequately.

what I want:
When the program executes it should automatically prompt the user to enter a number and exit when the user signals EOF through the keyboard

what's actually happening:
when I run the program, it sits there waiting for the user to hit enter THEN it prompts the user to enter a number; this somehow makes my code buggy

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // For exit() 

int main( ) {

    char c;
    while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF)  {

        int user_numbr = 0;
        int file_number = 0;
        int last_Appearance = 0;
        int index = 0;
        bool notFound;

        FILE *fptr;
        fptr = fopen("numbers.text", "r"); 

        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%d", &user_numbr);


        while ( !feof (fptr) ) {

            fscanf (fptr, "%d", &file_number);
            if ( feof (fptr) ) break;
            index++;

            if ( user_numbr == file_number ) {
                last_Appearance = index;
            }

        }
        fclose(fptr);

        if ( last_Appearance != 0) {
            printf("%d last appears in the file at position ", user_numbr);
            printf("%d\n", last_Appearance);
        }
        else if ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
            printf("%d does not appear in the file\n", user_numbr);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char c` should be `int c`. Also [while ( !feof (fptr) )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong) is wrong. You should check the return value of fscanf

Comment: `getchar()` blocks until the user hits a key.  And that's your very first line of executable code.  It's before your prompt.

Comment: You need to flush if you expect "Enter a number: " to be written.  To see when the input stream is closed (or, in horribly ambiguous/incorrect parlance "when EOF is sent"), just check the return value of scanf.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want the user should enter the file number only once, you should probably move

`printf("Enter a number: ");
 scanf("%d", &user_numbr);`

above the while loop.

Comment: the program must repeatedly ask user for a number until the user signals end of file by pressing (CTRL + D or CTRL + Z)

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358728/end-of-file-eof-in-c

Comment: EOF signifies end of file. The program should be able to identify the end of file. Why do you want the user to intervene by pressing Ctrl+D or Ctrl+Z. Instead, you can use break statement to get out of the loop.

Comment: this is an assignment and that's one of the requirements but no worries i was able to fix it.               ```while ( !feof(stdin) ) ```

Comment: this is also the same condition for the else if at the bottom.

Answer (score -1):

I found a fix. I'll post it if anyone who has this problem see's this post.

> > corrections:
> >     1)first while loop condition
> >     2)last else if condition

```
int main( ) {

    char c;
    while ( !feof(stdin) )  {

        int user_numbr = 0;
        int file_number = 0;
        int last_Appearance = 0;
        int index = 0;
        bool notFound;

        FILE *fptr;
        fptr = fopen("numbers.text", "r"); 

        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%d", &user_numbr);


        while ( !feof (fptr) ) {

            fscanf (fptr, "%d", &file_number);
            if ( feof (fptr) ) break;
            index++;

            if ( user_numbr == file_number ) {
                last_Appearance = index;
            }

        }
        fclose(fptr);

        if ( last_Appearance != 0) {
            printf("%d last appears in the file at position ", user_numbr);
            printf("%d\n", last_Appearance);
        }
        else if ( !feof(stdin) )
            printf("%d does not appear in the file\n", user_numbr);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Downvoting because this is wrong. See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56229458/asking-the-user-for-values-until-they-signal-end-of-file#comment99078860_56229458). All issues still apply