# No output for C program

Tags: c

I have some problems running my C program of character counting.

I wonder why there is no output whatever the input is. This is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int nc = 0;
    while (getchar() != EOF)
    {
       ++nc;
    }
    printf("%d\n", nc);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It works fine for me, how do you run it?

Comment: Works for me https://ideone.com/otUaE8 how do you input `EOF`?

Comment: How do you build the program? How do you run it?

Comment: Perhaps a console window closes before you get a chance to read the output.

Comment: YTou program loops untils it meets an OEF character.   Pressing Ctrl-C to end the program will end it before it executes the printf() statement  You need to press an EOF character so the printf() statemet executes,   In MS-DOS, and Windows, that's Ctrl-Z.  In Linux, you simply can't, but you can pipe in a file from the command line, your program will then count the number of bytes in that file.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy: Under Linux you type CTRL-D on the keyboard to get EOF

Comment: how are you signalling end of your input? You should use Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z, depending on your OS.

Comment: Does `yourprogram < yourcode.c` in a terminal/console window work?

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358728/end-of-file-eof-in-c